# Error installing Xposed Framework

Tags: root-access, xposed-framework, nexus-6p

I have a completely successfully rooted Nexus 6p running the tawin project. I checked many tutorials on how to flash the xposed file via recovery, but every time it comes up with an error stating that the updater process has ended with an error installing zip file. I have no idea why this occurs and am pretty sure the correct file was installed. How can I be able do do it?

[image: install error] [image: device details]
<sup>install error / device details (click images for larger variants)</sup>

Comment: Why are you not using the official ZIP? http://dl-xda.xposed.info/framework/sdk23/arm64/ Edit: Oh, there's the error: no space left on the device. I had this problem in Nexus 6. It had only 14.xx MB space in system partition, so Xposed didn't install (though it was enough BTW). I removed some unnecessary stuff (APKs) and everything went smooth. Make sure you make backup before removing anything from system partition.

Comment: See the last line before the red block: `cp: write error: no space left on device`. Looks like your `/system` partition is full.

Comment: i don't know why it says that since I still have a lot of space on my device. I tried putting the file into a different location and it said the same thing.

Comment: You need space in system partition, not in any other partition. Check the status yourself using `df` command.

Comment: ok so how do I delete the files in the system partition?

Comment: That's your homework. Perhaps others can help in that. Begin with a search of this site. There are definite full-blown solutions.

Comment: @DevinErsoy How did you solve it?

Comment: @RobinWinslow I solved it by deleting some files in the /system partition. I used an app called root browser(https://goo.gl/06aacc) to navigate there and cleaned up some files. You need very little space so no need to delete huge files but I had a large 1gig titanium backup file there so that's what caused the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the screenshot, there's an error saying `cp: write error: no space left on device`. It seems there's no space in `/system` partition of the device.

[image]

Flashing Xposed Framework would make use of the device's `/system` partition.

In case there are apps or anything bloating up the `/system` partition, try removing them and freeing some space from unused apps, and then re-flash it again with a recovery program like TWRP or ClockworkMod.

Before reflashing, do wipe the cache/Dalvik cache first. Whenever the errors appear after flashing, wipe the cache/Dalvik to be sure it's clean before flashing again.

Comment: I downloaded 'system app uninstaller' from Play Store, and then uninstalled some Google's apps, it solved it!

Comment: Even without `system app uninstaller`, only uninstalling some "bloatware" apps would do just to make room for some free space.